# Change Apple ID on iPad without losing data

Tags: itunes, ipad

I guess I confused you, so let me explain. I am a computer technician, dealing mostly with Windows computer and know a little about iPad and iOS in general. A customer called me because a Facebook application didn't work as expected. When browsing to her Facebook account within Safari, everything was OK, so I realized I should update the Facebook app. There was indeed a new version. The problem is that when she bought the iPad some other guy was too lazy to create a new Apple ID and used his own to install stuff. Every time I attempt to download a new app or update an existing one from Apple Store, I am asked to put the password for this guy's Apple ID and there is no option to use a different Apple ID. In the Settings, Apple Store and iTunes, the only Apple ID present is that of the owner! If I tap on it and select Sign Out, I can then go to Apple Store, select "Purchased Apps" and then I am asked to login to see them. At this point I am allowed to use another Apple ID. This does nothing as next time I try to use the Apple Store this annoying dialog asking for the password of the old Apple ID pops up!

I know that if I reset the device, I can then associate it with the proper Apple ID, but that's the problem! My customer has a lot of downloaded apps and photos she doesn't want to lose! Is there any method to remove this Apple ID once and for all WITHOUT losing data? Calling that guy to do it from his account is not an option, any other method?

Answer (score 2):

The "phenomenon" you experience has something to do with the actual apps your customer has on their iOS device. Those apps are purchased or downloaded by a person, which is not your customer and therefore using those apps would technically be against the EULA of the iTunes/App Store.

In order to rectify this, you want to do the following:

- Sign out of the other unknown person's iTunes/App Store account and sign in again using your customer's Apple ID.
- Delete the custom apps*) downloaded by that stranger and, if needed, re-download/purchase them with the correct account of your customer.
- Also worth checking is to sign out of iCloud (if it is used by that other person as well) as long as "Find My iPad" is not activated as well. If it is, you will need to have a proof of purchase (second hand purchases will not be accepted to my knowledge) and contact Apple to have it removed.

*) **IMPORTANT:** Deleting an app will also delete its user contents, which are stored for it on the device itself (like documents or login credentials). Remote data (e.g. information on Facebook) are not affected.

Once all this has been done, your nightmare will be at an end.